# Why does my x64 bit app able to load a x86 bit DLL?

Tags: c#, dll

I use Teststand 64 bit (National Instrument) with one of my DLL as follow :

- Teststand (64 bits) calls A.dll
- A.dll is targeting "Any CPU" and references B.dll
- B.dll is also targeting "Any CPU" and references C.dll
- C.dll targets "x86" and is in charge of database access (ADO.NET)

If I reference C.dll directly from Teststand 64 bits, I get the failure that it is unable to load the DLL as it recognize it to be 32 bits.  This was done by purpose and the result failed just as expected.

The problem here is that I don't understand why it works when Teststand calls A.dll.  C.dll succeeds in doing its job and I would have swear that this should have given an exception or any kind of error but no.

In my head and from what I've read about x86 and x64 together is that x64 can't call on x86 target software.

**Does someone has any kind of explanation for this?**

I would like to understand what is going on to better code my libraries because this is becoming for me a DLL hell!

Comment: Check that you don't have "Perfer 32-bit" checked in the options of the Teststand project. You may think it is running 64 bit but it actually is running 32.

Comment: No it is not Prefer 32-bit I confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old days, dll have always been compield for a specific binarity. We still ahve those around. I like to call the "native dll's".

.NET DLL and programms break with that. They are "bitness agnostic". The same compiled MSIL can be run as x64 and x32, depending on the framework executing it on the computer. It could even run as x128 or x16, if we ever would get frameworks and OS for that.

As long as you keep it to .NET DLL's, binarity is not an issue. It can sometimes enter with Memory constraints, but overall we ignore it. Once you start mixing in native DLL's, binarity suddenly becomes everything.

I can only tell that A.DLL and B.DLL seem to be .NET DLL's. I can not tell wich variant "Teststand.exe" and C.dll are. Or the ADO.Net DLLS being called by C.DLL. My best guess is that the the unbroken line of .NET Code is long enough, binarity does not mater. Testrand onyl cares what A.dll returns, not caring how it got that result. And B.dll can call C.dll the .NET way, where binarity does not mater (you never hand around naked pointers).

But if you try to call the x32 only C.DLL from Testrand directly, it seems to break.

Comment: Your best guess seems to follow the same assumption I had about this behavior.  I still question myself how this mecanism could pass through even if this seems to be the only logical way to answer though..

Comment: Well, native DLL have the issue that you have to translate between two kinds of pointers - x32 and x64. That is tricky. But a lot of work was invested into the .NET Framework so you would never handle naked pointers (unless you realy wanted too). This migth jsut be paying off. Alterantively, this might be a compiler error. If it was an issue, the Compiler should never allow code referenceing a x32 DLL to compile as anything but x32 itself. Any CPU should be either impossible or overridden at compilation.

Comment: Since nothing has evolved since a while on this discussion, I will accept your answer as being the nearest possible explanation we can get out of this discussion.  Thanks

Comment: Now that you reminded me of this, there might be an answer. Normally x32 Processes are limited to 2 GiB Memory. 3 GiB with the flag. The thing is, on x64 System the flag actually increases that to *4 GiB* of memory. Apparently all the Framework/no application stuff is moved to be above the 4GiB marker. actually x64 pointers are used. And for working in the "Virtual User space" the first digits are simply "shaved off". This same technology could allow a x86 compiled dll to be called by x64 process. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits

Comment: Sorry for my late response.  This actually makes really good sense.  Thanks for that link and answer which should be marked as the accepted answer